# How to store the value of a variable in state immediately when set state is async

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I am new to react and am trying to store the value in state for customer my code for getting the value of the dropdown is this:

```
handleChangeCC = customercode => {
    this.setState({ customercode });

    // var customer = customercode.map(o => o.label);
    // this.setState({ customer });

    var customer1 = customercode.label;
    this.setState({ customer: customer1 });

    console.log(`Option selected1:`, this.state.customer);
    this.getCustomerName();

    // console.log("Rec2:" + document.getElementById("CustomerCode").innerText);
  };
```

I am running function this.getCustomerName() in this function, The code for that is this:

```
getCustomerName = () => {
    var Items = [];

    var code = this.state.customer;
    console.log('CustomerCode:' + code);
    axios.post('https://localhost:44303/api/observation/GetCustomerName?' + '&code=' + code).then(response => {
      //console.log('Value=' + response.data);
      console.log('Response=' + response.data);
      response.data.map(item => {
        var obj = new Object();

        // obj.label = desc;
        obj.label = item;

        Items.push(obj);
        //this.setState({ locations: response.data });
      });
      this.setState({ customerName: Items });

      console.log('customerName:' + this.state.customerName);
    });
  };
```

I am setting code= this.state.customer in the function getCustomerName which I am running just after this.setState({ customer: customer1 }); in handleChangeCC function.

However as this.setState is an async function it is not updating the state immediately as a result of which I am getting code as null and my getCustomerName function does not work

How do I get around This? Is there a way to get the variable value of one function to another function. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pass the `customercode` into your `getCustomerName()` method, in this instance. `setState` will take a moment, so it's value won't be immediately available to your method. You would have to wait for the value to be in state and then call the method. By setting its' state *and* passing it to your method, you don't have to wait for the state update to complete.

Also, if you're just learning React I would look into using function based components instead of the legacy class components, if you have the option.

Comment: can you please tell me with the help of a code example of what you mean

Comment: In your `handleChangeCC`, you `setState({customercode})`, which isn't immediately available. So, also pass it to your other method `getCustomerName(customercode)`, using the argument in your async request instead of the unavailable state value.

Comment: yes got it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several techniques to get the latest value

## 2nd argument in setState

```js
this.setState({ customerName: Items }, () => {
    console.log('latest value', this.state.customerName);
});
```

> The second argument that can optionally be passed to setState is a callback function that gets called immediately after the setState is completed and the components get re-rendered.

More [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-second-argument-that-can-optionally-be-passed-to-setstate-and-what-is-its-purpose/#:%7E:text=The%20second%20argument%20that%20can%20optionally%20be%20passed%20to%20setState%20is%20a%20callback%20function%20which%20gets%20called%20immediately%20after%20the%20setState%20is%20completed%20and%20the%20components%20get%20re-rendered)

## async methods

```js
  updateA = async () => {
    this.setState({
      a: "test"
    });
    await (() => {})(); // or fetch or any async operation
    console.log(this.state.a);
  };
```

Do note this isn't recommended approach however current version of react supports it.